# Deploying a maven project in eclipse on Heroku

Tags: eclipse, maven, heroku

I created a Maven project in eclipse and tried to deploy it on the Heroku. I packaged everything into a war file and followed the instruction they have

```
 heroku deploy:war --war <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
```

The tutorial also mentioned if I'm in an app folder, I can omit the -app. But I'm not sure what's the app folder is? And where can I find the app name?

Answer (score 1):

I suffered with the same problem and found the answer by myself. From then, this is what I do every time:

*I login to my heroku account and create a new app with a name, say 'XYZ'. Now I put 'XYZ' instead of 'app-name' in the specified code snippet.*

Finally this is how it looks like:

`heroku deploy:war --war C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\XYZ.war   --app XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, the [Heroku Eclipse Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse) has its own [WAR deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#eclipse) feature. Just right-click on your app name in the **My Heroku Applications** view and click **Deploy**. It looks like you were following the [command line](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#command-line) instructions.

Comment: The problem was I created that Maven project before I installed the Heroku plugin. Does that mean I have to create a brand new Heroku project?

Comment: You can also [import an existing project as a Heroku project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse#importing-an-existing-app-into-eclipse) into Eclipse.